# Error al tratar de acceder a un archivo en XP

Tags: c#

```
    private string obtenerMD5(string sArchivo)
    {

        string sMd5 = "";
        Process compiler = new Process();

        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\sys\\progs\\md5 ";
        compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = sArchivo;
        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        compiler.Start();

        try
        {
            sMd5 = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Substring(0, 32);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se encontró archivo en ésta ruta: " + sArchivo, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            bHayError = true;
        }
        return sMd5;
    }`
```

Éste método recibe la dirección de un archivo con extensión .DLL
que se selecciona desde un OpenDialog. Ejecutándo el código
desde el sistema operativo windows 7 no hay problema, 
pero al momento de querer probarlo en XP salta el error.

Ignoro si pueda ser problema de permisos o alguna otra cosa.

Comment: cual es el error que recibís????

Comment: Probaste ejecutando la aplicación como administrador?

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: El error surge en ésta línea de código `sMd5 = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Substring(0, 32);`

Y entra al catch mostrándome el mensaje.

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti No, ya que en la máquina donde se programó en la cual hay windows 7 tampoco se tienen derechos de administrador.

Comment: @JulioJaquez, sería bueno que [edites tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/59208/edit) y agregues en texto cual es el error que te sale.

Comment: porque tienes que generar un md5 usando una aplicacion externa, no podrias usar las librerias que .net proporciona para generar el hash ?